# Empty list when using processes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing library to speed up CSV reading from files. I've done so using Pool and now I'm trying to do it with Process(). However when concatenating the list to create a dataframe, it's giving me the following error:

> ValueError: No objects to concatenate

To me it looks like the processes are overwriting the uber_data list. What am I missing here?

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Process
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

location = "/home/data/csv/"

uber_data = []

def read_csv(filename):

    return uber_data.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

def data_wrangling(uber_data):
    uber_data['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(uber_data['Date/Time'], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    uber_data['Dia Setmana'] = uber_data['Date/Time'].dt.weekday_name
    uber_data['Num dia'] = uber_data['Date/Time'].dt.dayofweek

    return uber_data

def plotting(uber_data):

    weekdays = uber_data.pivot_table(index=['Num dia','Dia Setmana'], values='Base', aggfunc='count')
    weekdays.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(8,6))
    plt.ylabel('Total Journeys')
    plt.title('Journey on Week Day')

def main():

    processes = []
    files = list(glob.glob(os.path.join(location,'*.csv*')))

    for file in files:
        print(file)
        p = Process(target=read_csv, args=[file])
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for i, process in enumerate(processes):
        process.join()

    print(uber_data)

    combined_df = pd.concat(uber_data, ignore_index=True)
    dades_mod = data_wrangling(combined_df)
    Plotting(dades_mod)

main()
```

Traceback is:

```
Process Process-223:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<timed exec>", line 17, in read_csv
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 255, in concat
    sort=sort,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 301, in __init__
    objs = list(objs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
Process Process-224:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<timed exec>", line 17, in read_csv
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 255, in concat
    sort=sort,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 301, in __init__
    objs = list(objs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
Process Process-221:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<timed exec>", line 17, in read_csv
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 255, in concat
    sort=sort,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 301, in __init__
    objs = list(objs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
Process Process-222:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
Process Process-225:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<timed exec>", line 17, in read_csv
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 255, in concat
    sort=sort,
  File "<timed exec>", line 17, in read_csv
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 301, in __init__
    objs = list(objs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 255, in concat
    sort=sort,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 301, in __init__
    objs = list(objs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
Process Process-220:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<timed exec>", line 17, in read_csv
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 255, in concat
    sort=sort,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 301, in __init__
    objs = list(objs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

[]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed eval> in <module>

<timed exec> in main()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    253         verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
    254         copy=copy,
--> 255         sort=sort,
    256     )
    257 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    302 
    303         if len(objs) == 0:
--> 304             raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
    305 
    306         if keys is None:

ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

Thank you

Comment: Please include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Done it, full traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `uber_data`'s in each process are not the same object as the `uber_data` in the main process.  You *can't* really share data between processes.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def read_csv(filename=r'c:\pyProjects\data.csv'):
    print(id(uber_data))
    uber_data.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

def main():

    processes = []
    for file in range(4):
        p = Process(target=read_csv)
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for i, process in enumerate(processes):
        process.join()

    return processes

if __name__ == '__main__':

    uber_data = []
    print(id(uber_data))
    ps = main()
```

Prints

```
PS C:\pyProjects> py -m tmp
2632505050432
1932359777344
2230288136512
2039196563648
2479121315968
```

You could use a Queue to send the data back to the main process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def read_csv(filename=r'c:\pyProjects\data.csv', q=None):
    q.put(pd.read_csv(filename))

def main(q):

    processes = []
    for file in range(4):
        p = Process(target=read_csv, kwargs={'q':q})
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for i, process in enumerate(processes):
        process.join()

    while not q.empty():
        print('.')
        uber_data.append(q.get(block=True))

    return processes


if __name__ == '__main__':

    uber_data = []
    q = Queue()
    ps = main(q)
    for thing in uber_data:
        print(thing.head().to_string())
        print('**')
```

Or you could use threads.

```
from threading import Thread
def g(filename):
    uber_data.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    uber_data = []
    threads = []
    for _ in range(4):
        threads.append(Thread(target=g, args=(r'c:\pyProjects\data.csv',)))
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    while any(t.is_alive() for t in threads):
        pass
    for thing in uber_data:
        print(thing.head().to_string())
        print('**')
```